# How do i put a string and user input into a new string using strcpy?

Tags: c, string, shell

Sorry if the title is a little bit confusing but basically im trying to make a command that will change the default shell of a user.

The user just needs to call the command (btb) and input the username e.g. `btb USERNAME`
btb being args[0] and USERNAME being args[1]. Now i need to make this into one string so that i can use it to make a system call `system("chsh -s /bin/bash USERNAME")`.

So far i have this

```
int Registerbtb(char **args)
{
  char command[50];
  strcpy(command, args[1]);
  system(command);
  return 1;
}
```

which is only taking the args[1] and putting that into command. But i need it to do is `strcpy(command, ("chsh -s /bin/bash %s", args[1]));` but that isnt possible.

What other way can i do this so that command will have the string `"chsh -s /bin/bash USERNAME"` in it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strcpy` is not the function you're looking for. You should instead use `snprintf` with a buffer to hold your string, if you know the size:

```
char buf[50];
snprintf(buf, sizeof(buf), "chsh -s /bin/bash %s", args[1]);
```

Keep in mind this above example suffers from a potential bug where the string will be truncated.

If you don't know the size of the username in beforehand you can call `snprintf` twice to dynamically allocate memory for your string, here is an example program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main(int argc, char **args) {
  char *str;

  // TODO check if argc is equal to one

  int length = snprintf(NULL, 0, "chsh -s /bin/bash %s", args[1]);
  assert(length >= 0); // TODO add proper error handling
  str = malloc(sizeof(char) * length);
  snprintf(str, length, "chsh -s /bin/bash %s", args[1]);

  printf("%s [%d]\n", str, length); // do something with the str
  free(str);
}
```

Or if you have it available on your system you can just use [asprintf](http://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf) to save you from an headache.

Comment: @Recap Great, remember to be careful if you use the example with a static buffer (I recommend to use asprintf, but you will have to set the preprocessor `_GNU_SOURCE` for it to work).